# Converges Or Diverges: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:e^{-\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Converges Or Diverges:

Attempt:

int_1^∞ e^(-sqrt(n)) dn

t = -sqrt(n); dt = -dn/(2*sqrt(n));

int -2*sqrt(n)/[-2*sqrt(n)] * e^(-sqrt(n)) dn

int (2t)*(e^t) dt

u = 2t; du = 2 dt; dv = e^t dt; v = e^t

(2t)*(e^t) - int 2*e^t

2t*(e^t) - 2*(e^t)

2 * (e^t) * (t - 1)

2 * e^(-sqrt(n)) * (-sqrt(n) - 1)

-2 * e^(-sqrt(n)) * (sqrt(n) + 1)

limit n->∞ [-2 * e^(-sqrt(n)) * (sqrt(n) + 1)]

[-2 * d/dn (sqrt(n) + 1)] / [d/dn e^sqrt(n)]

limit n->∞ -2*e^(-sqrt(n)) = 0

Comment: Please edit your answer and use TeX.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{n}}dn=\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-u}2udu<\infty$$

by integration by parts. So by the integral test the series converges.

Answer (score 5):

Converges by comparison with $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2\ln n}~=~\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$